# Swift optionals: language issue, or doing something wrong?

Tags: ios, swift

I am doing what I believe to be a very simple task. I'm trying to get a value out of a dictionary if the key exists. I am doing this for a couple keys in the dictionary and then creating an object if they all exist (basically decoding a JSON object). I am new to the language but this seems to me like it should work, yet doesn't:

```
class func fromDict(d: [String : AnyObject]!) -> Todo? {
    let title = d["title"]? as? String
    // etc...
}
```

It gives me the error: `Operand of postfix ? should have optional type; type is (String, AnyObject)`

HOWEVER, if I do this, it works:

```
class func fromDict(d: [String : AnyObject]!) -> Todo? {
    let maybeTitle = d["title"]?
    let title = maybeTitle as? String
    // etc...
}
```

It appears to be basic substitution but I may be missing some nuance of the language. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: `d["title"]` is an optional, you use `?` after an optional wrong. A use case for this operator would be `object?.property`, so it will only evaluate `object.property`, when `object` is **not** `nil` else it returns `nil`

Answer (score 3):

The recommended pattern is

```
if let maybeTitle = d["title"] as? String {
    // do something with maybeTitle
}
else {
    // abort object creation
}
```

It is possibly really a question of nuance. The form `array[subscript]?` is ambiguous because it could mean that the whole dictionary (`<String:AnyObject>`) is optional while you probably mean the result (`String`). In the above pattern, you leverage the fact that `Dictionary` is designed to assume that accessing some key results in an optional type.

After experimenting, and noticing that the `?` after `as` is just as ambiguous, more, here is my solution:

```
var dictionary = ["one":"1", "two":"2"]
// or var dictionary = ["one":1, "two":2]
var message = ""
if let three =  dictionary["three"] as Any? {
    message = "\(three)"
}
else {
    message = "No three available."
}
message // "No three available."
```

This would work with all non-object Swift objects, including Swift Strings, numbers etc. Thanks to Viktor for reminding me **that `String` is not an object in Swift**. +

If you know the type of the values you can substitute `Any?` with the appropriate optional type, like `String?`

Comment: I thought so too, **but** that throws an error in the playground, like @vacawama mentioned. The `NSString` in the dictionary as a value is showed as a type of `(String, AnyType)` and can not be casted to `String?` in the same line. ... And your *maybeTitle* wouldn't be maybe anymore, else it wouldn't be set right before going into the if brackets.

Comment: What if the dictionary is of type `[String:AnyObject]!` like the OP's dictionary.  This doesn't work in a Playground for me.

Comment: `if let three = dictionary["three"] as NSObject?` works if the dictionary is `[String:AnyObject]!`.

Comment: Yes that is the analogous solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few of things going on here.

1) The `?` in `d["title"]?` is not correct usage.  If you're trying to unwrap `d["title"]` then use a `!` but be careful because this will crash if `title` is not a valid key in your dictionary.  (The `?` is used for *optional chaining* like if you were trying to call a method on an optional variable or access a property.  In that case, the access would just do nothing if the optional were `nil`). It doesn't appear that you're trying to unwrap `d["title"]` so leave off the `?`.  A dictionary access always returns an optional value because the key might not exist.

2) If you were to fix that:

```
let maybeTitle = d["title"] as? String
```

The error message changes to: **error: '(String, AnyObject)' is not convertible to 'String'**

The problem here is that a `String` is not an object.  You need to cast to `NSString`.

```
let maybeTitle = d["title"] as? NSString
```

This will result in `maybeTitle` being an `NSString?`.  If `d["title"]` doesn't exist or if the type is really `NSNumber` instead of `NSString`, then the optional will have a value of `nil` but the app won't crash.

3) Your statement:

```
let title = maybeTitle as? String
```

does not unwrap the optional variable as you would like.  The correct form is:

```
if let title = maybeTitle as? String {
    // title is unwrapped and now has type String
}
```

So putting that all together:

```
if let title = d["title"] as? NSString {
    // If we get here we know "title" is a valid key in the dictionary, and
    // we got the type right.  title has now been unwrapped and is ready to use
}
```

`title` will have the type `NSString` which is what is stored in the dictionary since it holds objects.  You can do most everything with `NSString` that you can do with `String`, but if you need `title` to be a `String` you can do this:

```
if var title:String = d["title"] as? NSString {
    title += " by Poe"
}
```

and if your dictionary has `NSNumber`s as well:

```
if var age:Int = d["age"] as? NSNumber {
    age += 1
}
```

Comment: Since there is automatic translation between NSString and String; you are saving an NSString into a String without casting. It is only confusing to use NSString at all, if String is wanted.

Comment: It is a shame that we have to use `NSString`, but that is fact of life when dealing with dictionaries that come from Cocoa and Cocoa touch calls.  If the dictionary had been `[String:Any]` life would have been much easier.

Comment: As every NSObject, NSString is already an optional, so there is no need to use `as?` instead of `as`

Comment: The `as?` allows the app to survive if the dictionary didn't have the type we expected.  Casting to an `NSString` when the value is really an `NSNumber` will cause a crash.  If the dictionary comes from an outside source, it is dangerous to just assume you know what type the values are.

Comment: Try this code in a Playground.  Then change 23 to be a string. `var d:[String: AnyObject]! = ["name":"Fred", "age":23]
if let age:String = d["age"] as? NSString {
    println("age is a String")
} else if let age:Int = d["age"] as? NSNumber {
    println("age is an Int")
}`

Comment: You are right, thanks for teaching me. If I understood correctly: `NSString` is translated to `String?` (works for me). But using a cast with `as?` also returns `nil` if the cast fails?